# First-order linear partial differential equation with boundary conditions

Tags: boundary-value-problem

I am trying to solve this boundary-value problem:

$$u_x(x,y) + u_y(x,y) + u(x,y) = 0$$
$$u(0,y) = 1$$
$$u(x,0) = 1$$

[Image version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaIWO.png)

I tried to use the method of characteristics, but it seems that it is only for initial-value problems.
I would thank any help

By using the method of characteristics I solve the corresponding ODEs system and get the general solution

u(x,y) = f(x-y)exp(-x)

but, when I try to obtain f for one boundary condition, the answer don't match with the other boundary condition. I don't know what is really happening

Comment: Would you like to share what you have tried/thought of so far? (If yes, please edit the question ***body*** as people usually votes to close questions before reading the comments)

Comment: Thanks, I will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a line $x-y = c$, your pde says $u(x,x-c) e^{x}$ is constant.  If that line intersects both of your boundaries and the values you get there are not consistent with each other, it says your boundary value problem has no solution.

Comment: The line can intersect one boundary or another, not both, and depending of C. In this case, what can I say about the solution? And how can I express it?

Comment: If you're interested only in $x, y \ge 0$ (which you neglected to mention) then yes, the line $x-y=c$ will intersect only one boundary and there is no inconsistency.  So what's the problem?  Your solution will be expressed in "piecewise" fashion: if $x-y \ge 0$ then $\ldots$ else $\ldots$.

Comment: You will have a lack of differentiability on the line $x=y$, though.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't think in express the solution in piecewise fashion, I wanted to express it be a continuous function.